# How does Spark on top of Cassandra affect Cassandra data modeling?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, datastax

The first thing I learnt when dealing with Cassandra is that you need to be very careful about your data model as Cassandra does not support joins, aggregations, etc. So you model your data according to your queries, use extensive de-nomarlization, etc.

But let's say I have decided to run Spark on top of Cassandra. Spark will allow for doing joins and aggregations, and different computations on the data.

So my question is when modeling my data in Cassandra and having in mind that I will run Spark on it do I need to change my models so that they suit Spark for faster computations or I still need to stick to the best practices for data modeling in plain Cassandra?

For example if I have Table1 and Table2 in cassandra which hold the same data but in Table1 one the data is keyed by Key1, Key2 (partion key) and in table two the data is keyed by Key1, Key3 (partion key), these are essentially two views of my data which are ready for fast quering. If I need to query the data by Key1, Key2, Key3, I will have to create a third table Table3. But knowing that I can query and join Table1 and Table2 in Spark on top of Cassandra I might not need to create Table3?

Answer (score 0):

Table1+Table2 means two reads while only Table3 means one read. So Table3 with a composite primary key would be faster